# Why does the Diophantine equation $2x^2\:-5y^2\:=\:1$ have no solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to figure out why the equation,

$2x^2\:-5y^2\:=\:1$

has no solutions. I have tried taking the equation mod $2$,$4$, and $5$, but when I do this I am not sure what I am supposed to look for. I would really appreciate an explanation on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo $5$, *x* can be only $0,\pm1,\pm2.~$ Squaring and then doubling, we have $0,2,3$, all of which are $\neq1\bmod5.~$ $($We were required to find $2x^2\equiv1\bmod5)$.

Comment: How would I solve the equation mod $2$?

Comment: @SeanC: $\bmod2$ is undecisive.

Comment: Why is it undecisive?

Comment: @SeanC Hey buddy!

If you take that equation $mod \: 2$, then you end up with $1 \equiv 1$, which doesn't tell us anything

Comment: @SeanC: It doesn't help you arrive at any conclusion.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused as to why it is inconclusive. Is there an easy explanation?

Comment: @SeanC If you don't get a contradiction in a given modulus it doesn't tell you that there are integer solutions. There might be another argument (such as another modulus  where one gets a contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ 1 \equiv  2x^2\overset{(\ \ )^{\large 2}}\Rightarrow 1\equiv 4x^4\overset{\rm Fermat}\equiv 4\,\Rightarrow\, 5\mid 4-1\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$